# Store files in database with DBIC using Catalyst

Tags: mysql, perl, file, upload, catalyst

I'm using Perl Catalyst framework to build an application that needs to store several files in a MySQL database (among other things). I want to store the name, path, extension, etc of the files to retrieve them later; because they are supposed to be accessible from the application (e.g: a PDF document uploaded for someone, must be available for download later). Can I do this? I found several ways to do it in PHP, but none for perl. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I know I can access to some information using Catalyst::Request::Upload. I used this in the past for BLOB storage, but I dont't know how to get file information nor how to know where does catalyst store tmp files.

So, basically, the questions that arise when trying to this are:

1. How to know where are my files being stored once I submit them?
2. How to copy these files (which I assume go to a tmp folder somewhere) to a folder in my computer/server?
3. How to retrieve these files once I have them stored?

**EDIT 2**

I've checked again the documentation for Catalyst::Request::Upload (http://search.cpan.org/~jjnapiork/Catalyst-Runtime-5.90114/lib/Catalyst/Request/Upload.pm) and found out how to know **where are my files being stored** and **how to copy them to a new non-tmp location**. The only question that remains:

**How do I generate a download link for these files??**

Comment: Yes. Of course. Are you using DBIx::Class or just a plain DBI handle? Do you want to store the whole file content, or just the name, path and extension? Are those files uploaded by the user, or are they in your local file system? If the latter, why do you need them in the DB? Can you not work with the file system directly? Are they related to your other data?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer.

1. DBIx::Class
2. just name, path and extension (I dont want my DB to get too bold)
3. The files are uploaded by the users.

Hope it helps :) and thanks again

Comment: Ok. That sounds straight-forward. You should have a DBIC based model in your Catalyst app. All you need to do is use it in a controller and pass the data in. It's really hard to tell you anything else. We don't know what exactly you are struggling with, what your level of expertise is or if you actually tried it yourself. Noone is just going to write code for you though, especially since there is not enough information to do that. Sorry.

Comment: So... what is the question? Are you asking how to insert a record into a database table?

Comment: I'll edit the question for better understanding.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, where are the files? That's important to download them.

Comment: Haven't tested it yet, but it seems that I can config the Catalyst app to have a tmp directory, with:

   `__PACKAGE__->config( uploadtmp => '/path/to/tmpdir' );`

And then use the copy_to method of the $upload object to copy it to another folder in my app directory (e.g: myapp/files/).

Answer (score 2):

The solution was pretty straight-forward.

- First Make sure your 'tmp' folder is configured in the Catalyst app file (e.g: MyApp.pm).
- Now, use Catalyst::Request::Upload to create the file object with the uploaded file. Sort of...

  ```
   my $upload = $req->upload('input_field_name');
  ```
- Now make sure you get all the data you want to store from the file. I, personally, got just the filename, MIME Type and size.

  ```
  my $filename = $upload->filename;
  my $size = $upload->size;
  my $type = $upload->type;
  ```
- Store into the database.
- Now, create a folder within the public content of the page to copy the files to, and perform the copy like:

  ```
  $upload->copy_to('path/to/the/public/folder');
  ```
- To retrieve the files, just create a link with the base URL to the public folder and the filename you stored in the database.

Hope it helps someone... it was pretty obvious, though; but it cracked my head a little.